# how to remove elements of the same type from a list in python

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list and I want to remove the elements of the same type from it - I tried to do it this way but it is an obvious nonsense:

```
list =  [14, 5, 53, "Mercedes", 5, 66, 5, 4, "BMW", 5, 4, 6, "Tesla", 111, 333, 22, 33, 44]

for each_element in list:
    while(type(each_element)) == <int> in list: 
          list.remove(each_element)
```

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? This question is asking how to filter through a list based on the type of object in said list. Not simply how different types are defined. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @AaronBrandhagen right, and the OP doesn't know how to determine the type of an object, which is what the target duplicate addresses, not "how types are defined". If you still disagree, you can vote to re-open.

Comment: Determine the type of object....to then filter through a list and remove elements of that type. Just by looking at OP's code, it's clear his question is much more involved than simply identifying/determining object types.

Comment: i wouldn't say it was a duplicate. i was not asking about how to get a type of an object, but about how to filter out a sequence based on object types

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, so I'll give you a method to solve. Start a new list, called `newlist`. Have a separate `list` or `set` that you use to identify which types have already been added to `newlist` (perhaps called `typelist`).Use a for loop to iterate through your original list, adding to `newlist` if and only if the type of the item you're trying to add isn't in `typelist`; when you do add to `newlist`, append the type of your item to `typelist`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it simpler using list comprehension.

```
values =  [14, 5, 53, "Mercedes", 5, 66, 5, 4, "BMW", 5, 4, 6, "Tesla", 111, 333, 22, 33, 44]

newlist = [value for value in values if type(value) != int]
```

*PS: Don't save `list` as as variable as it 's a python class*

Comment: @iDrwish must read ` in values ` instead of ` in list `

Comment: @ack looks like it's fixed :)